# When operators work on active objects and when on selected?

Tags: scripting, operator

After spending some hours debugging [Active object does not match selected after duplicate()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71027/active-object-does-not-match-selected-after-duplicate) I've got more generic question.

How do I know if operator works on active object or on selected?